Can anyone tell me where this card is from?

I've bought a lot of second hand board games lately, so there may be a couple posts like this from me whilst I try to figure out where some random pieces are from.

How big is this? Playing card sized?

This looks like a holder card for sorting card stacks of cards with those three symbols. If you have another card that has one of those symbols printed on, that might figure it out faster

It is playing card size, and I have found some small circle game pieces that are the same same patterns as the shape on the card, no other cards have been found though

I have discovered it is an abilities expansion for mint delivery!

It is from Mint Delivery. It relates to the Player Abilities optional rules.


Could you support that? Looking into the game Mint Delivery, I see no cards that look anything like the one in the picture. Info like what the expansion is called, how the card fits into the game when it looks different from anything else in the game, etc would help.

Found this: https://www.thegamesteward.com/products/mint-delivery

Also this shows the card directly.

One more: https://youtu.be/7gN36ilNSxQ?si=7yM8oX_mPppJ76Yl&t=140
